# How to "push up" old questions in SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, specific-question, unanswered-questions

Hi,

If I asked a question in SO a few months ago, and is still open, if I edit the question will it come up fresh in today's questions?
If not, how could one "push" up "older" questions still not answered?
My understanding is that new questions always appear first and as you move through pages you see older questions (i.e. by date).
Is this possible by editing the question with the new findings in case it helps being answered or is it better to start a new post?
Or the idea is to edit the page and stay where it is? I am not sure how this works in SO.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The post will rise, if someone adds/edits an answer or you/someone edits the question

If you want to attract more eyeballs, you may want to offer a bounty(only available for posts which are atleast 48 hrs old )

Comment: @abel:So if I asked the question 5 months ago and I edit it again today, I will see it in the top of today's questions?

Comment: @user155461  Questions that are selected for the homepage, depend on the user viewing it too. See [jeff's post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/)

Comment: @user155461 a bounty is going to draw the most attention to your question and will keep in the light for a few days.

Comment: @abel:I updated a question, and then pressed on "Questions".My edited question was not in the list of fresh questions even though I had the relevant tag (specifically java) in my SO questions page related tags. Why is this?

Comment: @jzd:The bounty is subtracted from my points?

Comment: @user155461 yes, that is how bounties work.

Comment: @user155461 Try refreshing and you should find the question on that page. SO gets a lot of questions, it's easier to try this on a sister site like [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)